# how to use appledoc to generate an Apple-like documentations

Tags: xcode, appledoc

I am reading on the article how to generate an Apple-like HTML documentation at [here](http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc-docs-examples-basic/). My questions are what the command lines are used for. How can we combine command lines and appledoc xcode project to generate a HTML.

Comment: I doubt that most people are familiar with the 'appledoc' project, so you might want to explain your question a bit more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I haven't used 'appledoc', but from a quick look at the page you linked it appears that it's an open-source command-line utility. So the first step will be to compile the 'appledoc' program itself, and then stick it in a directory that's in your path, such as `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin/`.

The next step is to try to use it to generate some documentation (assuming that you've already created the markdown files that it consumes). Open a terminal window, navigate to the directory where your files are, and then use the command given at the top of the page that you linked:

```
appledoc --project-name appledoc --project-company "Gentle Bytes" --company-id com.gentlebytes --output ~/help .
```

If you want to use 'appledoc' to regenerate your documentation every time you build some project, you can add a "Run Script" build phase to an existing target in your project, or create a new target just for documentation that has nothing but a "Run Script" build phase. Either way, the script in that phase should be shell script containing a command similar to the one above (though you'll probably want to specify the source directory explicitly rather than just using the 'current' directory, i.e. `.`).

Answer (score 18):

I'm the author of appledoc tool. The tool is intended to be used as answered by Caleb above. Recommended installation method is to clone repository from GitHub, open project in Xcode, build and optionally copy binary to your path as suggested above. Additionally, you must also copy template files required for running the tool to one of predefined paths. All the steps required are described in the readme file on appledoc page on [GitHub](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc), see Quick Install section.

There are also other methods for installing - all contribution from users:

- You can use `install-appledoc.sh` script included in the git repository.
- There's also [homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) recipe available, although it doesn't install template files to my understanding (see [this link](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/10814)).

For any additional questions go to [appledoc Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/appledoc). I just created it few days ago, so there's no content at the moment of this writing, but feel free to ask questions there.

Answer (score 4):

As I found on this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appledoc/WGCHGRoFZ8c), you can generate a complete HTML documentation of your code with this command line:

> appledoc --project-name BabelCPP --project-company "My Name"
>   --company-id com.mycompany --no-create-docset --output ./doc/ .

The last "." is the path to your code.