# still got nothing after can display documentation in Documentation, appledoc

Tags: iphone, ios

I have been spending a while working on how to generate a documentation via appledoc with the help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807780/how-to-use-appledoc-to-generate-an-apple-like-documentations#comment12492431_9807780).

Now I can see my new library displayed on the left hand side from Xcode/Help/Documentation. However, it is empty after all. I am still figuring out but it seems no moving forward after all.
What I am doing is example.m  is an example file that I wanna display

> example.m
>
> /** Query the geonames.org service for the name of the place near the
> given
>
> *position (WGS84)
>
> *@param latitude The latitude for the position.
>
> *@param longitude The longitude for the position.   */
>
> - (void)findNearbyPlaceNameForLatitude:(double)latitude longitude:(double)longitude;

Now I am doing

> appledoc --project-name Example --project-company "MY_COMPANY"
> --company-id ABC.com -o "/Users/Desktop/AppleDoc_Example/" -h -d -n ~/Users/Desktop/AppleDoc_Example/example.m

After launching xcode, here it is

[image]

Does any one know what the problem is... Please advice me... Any comments are welcomed here.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been using appledoc for a couple of years and I think you are missing the `--install-docset` argument which tells appledoc to install the docset into Xcode. I suspect appledoc is working fine, just not updating Xcode with the latest build.

You can see the script I use at https://github.com/drekka/dUsefulStuff/blob/master/scripts/createDocumentation.sh which may help.

Comment: I have just do the following like you just recommended :*appledoc --project-name Example --project-company "MY_COMPANY" --company-id ABC.com -o "/Users/tranvutuan/DevTool/AppleDoc_Example/" -h -d -n ~/DevTool/AppleDoc_Example/example.m*.... But I still got nothing... Using script is my next step in appledoc tutorial....

Comment: Ok now I figured it out why I could not generate the documentation for an example.m from OP. The reason is I was missing **'@implementation example'** statement for m file ( or if it is the header file, we have to have @interface statement ). By carelessness, somehow, I did ignore them.....Anyways... thanks for all your helps, it is very valuable to me...

Comment: The link you mentioned is dead. **404**